# Induction in reverse: For $P(n):x_1\cdots x_n\le\left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)^n$, if $P(n)$ holds then $P(n-1)$ holds (for $n>1$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The problem is stated as follows:

> $$P(n) : x_1 \cdots x_n \le \left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}{n}\right)^n,\quad x_1, \cdots, x_n \ge 0$$
> The question states:
>
> By setting $x_n = \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}$ prove $P(n)$ implies $P(n-1)$ whenever $n \gt 1$.

I understand the principle, for this portion of the question we are showing the base case. However, I am at a loss: I will show my work thus far -

Given:

$$P(n) : x_1 \cdots x_n \le \left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}{n}\right)^n, \quad x_1, \cdots ,x_n \ge 0$$

Then

$$x_1 \cdots x_n \le \left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n} + \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)^n$$

Which gives

$$x_1 \cdots x_n \le \left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)^n$$ via simple arithmetic.

But at this point I am stumped. I don't have the toolkit available to me to see how to convert this into a proof. The book lists the answer as:

> We get $P(n-1)$ from the inequality $x_1 \cdots x_{n-1} \left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right) \le \left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)^n$

But I am unsure how the author got $\left(\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)$ on the side of the sequence, or how we have changed the sequence limits in order to prove this. It seems intuitive it is true - but I can't learn anything from failing at this problem unless I understand how the author arrived here! I understand we can do something like:

$$x_1 \cdots x_n \le (\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1})^{n-1} \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}$$

But this doesn't seem to help the situation, since to get it over to the other side I would need to divide, right?

Can anyone offer some help? This seems like one of the proofs that require a "shock of insight" to solve. Thank you!

Comment: You did not replace $x_n = \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1}}{n-1}$ as indicated. First, you left an $x_n$ on the left hand side, then the sum on the right hand side is not the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's from Cauchy.
$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i=\frac{1}{n}.(\frac{n}{n-1})\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i=\frac{1}{n}(\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i+\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i)$

Then consider $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i$ as $a_n$

We can get that $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i\geqslant\sqrt[n]{(\prod\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i)\cdot(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i)}$

Obviously we get the answer.I believe it's called the "forward and backward"

Comment: Wow...to think I graduated two semesters of discrete math years ago. This book consistently flies over my head. I would have never guessed. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.